# Moving attributes from one entity to another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm have a multi-list app that has an entity with several attributes for each list (i.e. List1 - item, description, qty...List2 - item, description, qty).

I have `UITableView`'s for each list set to have two sections (section 0 "not checked" and section 1 "checked" with the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method).

I want to use a button move the selected row's data to the second entity and remove it from the first.

I have put the button in a `UIView` in the footer of section 1 and made it segue to the destination viewController, just without any data transferred.

The only information I have found during google searching is on data migration and migrating assists of a business (fail), but I don't really think this is what I am looking for...is it? Or what is this process called? I am also using `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the objectContext (I think I said that right).

Please keep in mind very new to coreData and that I'm still not able to convert Obj-c into Swift yet, so Swift is all I've been learning. Also, any explanation would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: so there is no difference in the data held in the two entities, just that you have transferred from one to the other?  

if that is the case, then entityOwner is just another attribute which you use to decide which list to display the entry in

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question/answer. The user will begin by entering data into list saved by entity1. As they "check off" the items they can move the selected rows to the second list, entity2. The purpose it to keep them from having to constantly add and delete the same information each time they want to move it to another list. Once they have it in the app they can move it from entity to entity without needing to enter all the information again. Is this what you are trying to explain? if so what is entityOwner?

Comment: when you described moving the data from one entity to the other, I thought of that in terms of the data initially being 'owned' by the first entity (controller) and then by the second, nothing more than that.

I think you're describing something a bit different to that - does your first list remain in place, so that you don't **move** the data to the second controller, you **add** it to the list?

Comment: I need the data to be removed from the first entity and added to the second. Picture a shopping list and shopping cart. You enter the data on your list but when you move it into the cart you take it off your list. (hopefully that makes sense).

Comment: cool - so there's only one set of data shared between the two lists
You may add some attributes as you move it from one to the other, but you could store it all in a single list, with an attribute to indicate if any given row is in the shopping list or the cart

Comment: Yea, I'm assuming that would work. Would I have to delete pretty much everything I've done and make it all under one entity or how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101269/discussion-between-will-zimmer-and-russell).